# how to combine two construct variants into a single construct variant in matillion

Tags: json, matillion

I have converted JSON values into tabular using construct variant in matillion. But I need to combine the output of the two construct variants into one.

Output of construct variant 1:

```
[{                                          
    "StepId": 1,
    "ParameterFileGroup": 1,
    "ParameterGroup": 1,
    "Parameter": 4,
    "Filter": "",
    "SortKey": "",
    "Skip": -1,                            
    "ParameterFileGroup": 1,
    "ParameterGroup": 1,
```

Output of construct variant 2:

```
{
        "ConditionId": 4,
        "Threshold": "37",
        "ActionPlan": 3,
        "TriggerAction": 5
```

The ouput I require is as follows

```
[{                                          
    "StepId": 1,
    "ParameterFileGroup": 1,
    "ParameterGroup": 1,
    "Parameter": 4,
    "Filter": "",
    "SortKey": "",
    "Skip": -1,                            
    "ParameterFileGroup": 1,
    "ParameterGroup": 1,
{
        "ConditionId": 4,
        "Threshold": "37",
        "ActionPlan": 3,
        "TriggerAction": 5
}}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join and transpose rows component